# Preview Image shows differently in Chrome only

Tags: google-chrome, offset

This is the site:
http://grafistas.com.gr/perle/?page_id=105

If you open it and go hover over a product title an image will pop up. In all browsers seems to be okay.

But in Chrome the image is way at the left.

Inside the js file, the     xOffset     is positive number but the     yOffset     is a negative number. Does Chrome not understand negative numbers?

I also read somewhere that a possible fix would be to load the js file at the very end so that the image could be loaded and Chrome would read its width/height. I tried it but nothing changed.

Anyone knows what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the class that the preview image was embeded and now it works perfect! Thanks me! :P